# How to convert lat lng to xy with custom center point in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a google map. I placed a tileOverlay on it (a fictional game world). The game uses a x,y coordinate system. I need to convert all my lat lng coordinates to this exact x,y system.

I picked two spots on the map and got their real xy values from the game.
Then got the lat lng of these two spot from the android map.
Then used this code:

```
// First spot data
static Double game_1_x = 1972.606;
static Double game_1_y = 3817.044;
static Double map_1_lng = 42.108797;
static Double map_1_lat = 43.152977;

// second spot data
static Double game_2_x = -1154.11;
static Double game_2_y = -2715.203;
static Double map_2_lng = -48.3334;
static Double map_2_lat = -80.346344;

Double LAT = latFromMarker;
Double LON = lngFromMarker;

// this works
// all markers added with this equation fall on the correct longitude line
Double X = game_1_x + (LON - map_1_lng) * (game_1_x - game_2_x) / (map_1_lng - map_2_lng);

// this does not work
// markers added using this equation are always too far north or south of where they need to be
Double Y = game_1_y + (LAT - map_1_lat) * (game_1_y - game_2_y) / (map_1_lat - map_2_lat);
```

The reason the "y" transformation does not work correctly is because the latitude lines are not equally spaced due to Google Maps API v2 Mercator Projection.

I need to know what I need to do to account for this fluctuation. I'm sure there is some advanced equation or something, but I've googled effortlessly for hours and have came up empty handed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do some math like this...

[image]

Something like `cos(alpha) *R=r`...?

Not really a math major nor good at math...
so you should ask it in the [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

**=-=-=-=-=-=-= OR =-=-=-=-=-=-=**

Since what you care is actually `D:d`

you can use the `computeDistanceBetween(LatLngFrom, LatLngTo)` function and find the `D:d` by comparing the distance between two pair of two points with same lng and different lat. (say how long is 1 degree lat in lng 0 vs lng 45)

For more about [computeDistanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance).